# Can't resolve referenced projects

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created a new ASP.NET 5 MVC project named "TestIt". I then added a new ASP.NET 5 Class Library project named "TestIt.ClassLibrary" to my solution and referenced "TestIt.ClassLibrary" to the MVC project i.e. "TestIt".

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to access any of the methods in the class library project -- at least I can say that IntelliSense is not helping me -- see below:

Any idea why I'm having this problem?

I want to point out that I updated the projects to use DNX46 (both of them). Also want to point out that the class library is an ASP.NET 5 Class Library project which generates NuGet packages.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here's the project.json file for the ASP.NET 5 MVC project:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "TestIt.ClassLibrary": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OAuth": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx46": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your class library build without error using `dnu build`command ? as your class library is a part of your solution, remove the version : `"TestIt.ClassLibrary": ""` in the dependencies section of your project.json

Comment: (1) Where are the two projects located relative the solution root on disk? Is the folder containing the second project in the `global.json` file? (2) Do you get any compilation errors for the class library?

Comment: Also, can you share the class library's `project.json` file?

Answer (score 0):

Check your project.json file to ensure that you have a dependency reference to your class library.

It should look something like this:

```
"dependencies": {
      "TestIt.ClassLibrary": "1.0.0-*",
```

EDIT:
Add this to the top of your project file to see if it resolves the intellisense.

```
"webroot": "wwwroot",
```

Comment: I checked the project.json and the references are there. More interestingly, if I debug my code, it works and I can step through the code and get into methods in the class library project. So, looks like everything is working except for IntelliSense and this makes writing code very difficult.

Comment: Can you post your project.json file located in the web project?

Comment: I just found something that seems like a similar problem: https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/245

Comment: What should I have in my global.json file under projects? Currently, I have the generic etnries:
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update1"
  }
}

Comment: Global is fine; It's your project.json file that if corrupt, can cause intelli-sense to work incorrectly.

Comment: Just added the project.json file to the main post i.e. the question.

Comment: As I suspected, try adding the edited portion of my answer and cross your fingers. Let me know if this works.  I suspect, that this minor bug; without adding the webroot specification, causes the IDE to have trouble finding/determining root project structure.

Comment: Is it important where I place it? I added it after "compilationOptions" and before "dependencies" in the project.json for the MVC app but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: I moved it to the very top of the project.json and that didn't seem to make a difference either.

Comment: Okay, the only other suggestion I have is this, instead of stipulating a version for your reference, just make it an empty value.

For example:  

Current: "TestIt.ClassLibrary": "1.0.0-*",

Change it to: "TestIt.ClassLibrary": "",

No space between the quotes.

Comment: That didn't help either! Thank you for trying. If you come up with any other ideas, please let me know as this is still an issue at this point. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but the setup was different. I have a primary project that is a .xproj and targets dnx451 and dnxcore50. I have a class library that is a "Portable Class Library" (.csproj). I experimented with different configurations of the portable class library. By the time I found one that built I had messed something up because intellisense didn't work for any code that referenced classes in the class library.

I eventually determined that the wrap project.json files that were created never got updated when I would change my class library's "targets".

This may or may not be your problem. I don't even know if a wrap folder would be created in your scenario.

I resolved my issue by:

1. Removing the references to the class library from project.json in my main project
2. Closing VS
3. Deleting the "wrap" folder in the solution directory and also the global.json file in the solution directory. You may want to open these files and make sure there isn't anything you want to keep. In my case the only references inside were to the project I was having issues with.
4. Open VS.
5. Add the reference to your class library in your primary project, a new wrap folder and file should get created, and hopefully it is correct this time.

Technically I did more steps than this. I rebuilt my entire class library, but I don't think that was the problem, if it was then you might try rebuilding your class library from scratch with the settings that are working for the build.

Good luck, I hope this helps!