# Specify packages location

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, class-library

I want to specify where the packages should be placed when I compile my ASP.NET 5 Class Library project. I found some articles that talk about specifying this in the global.json but they seem a bit outdated.

Where do I specify the packages location for my ASP.NET 5 Class Library project so that every time I compile it, it'll produce an updated version of the package?

Comment: To build NuGet package of a class library you must use the `dnu pack` command. for exemple `dnu pack --configuration Release --out ..\out`. But why do you want to do that on each build ? Do you mean each time you build it using `VS` or on each nightly build ?

Comment: I'm really trying to find a work around to another problem that I described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34476870/cant-resolve-referenced-projects/34477116?noredirect=1#comment56696732_34477116

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:

1. Specify the `--out` argument when running `dnu pack`.
2. Have a post build step that copies the files. [Here's an example](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling/project.json#L59-L67)